# Read value from Arduino web server

Tags: php, python

I am trying to write Python code to read a simple temperature value from the local Arduino server.

This is my source page:

```
<font color=black size=7>Senzorji DS18B20<font color=black size=7><br />
<font color=black size=7>Kurnica: [26.00] &#176;
C
<font color=green size=7><font color=black size=7><br />
<font color=black size=7>Zunaj: [33.13] &#176;
C
<font color=green size=7><font color=black size=7><br />
<font color=black size=7>Garaza: [27.62] &#176;
C
<font color=black size=7><br />
<br />
Senzor DHT11 - Garaza<font color=black size=7><br />
<font color=black size=7>Temperatura v garazi: [24.00] &#176;
C
<font color=green size=7><font color=black size=7><br />
<font color=black size=7>Vlaga v garazi: [17.00] %
<br />
<br />
Senzor DHT11 - Stara kurilnica<font color=black size=7><br />
<font color=black size=7>Temperatura v stari kurilnici: [23.00] &#176;
C
<font color=green size=7><font color=black size=7><br />
<font color=black size=7>Vlaga v stari kurilnici: [14.00] %
<font color=green size=7>
```

I want to read the value in square brackets with Beautiful soup but no luck. I cannot find my case. All examples are more complex; mine is simple but I do not know.

I'm using Raspberry Pi.

With PHP, I wrote simple code. It changed for me and it worked.
This is my PHP code:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);   
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$arduino91 = file_get_contents("http://192.168.5.91/");
$radiator = get_string_between($arduino91, "(povratek): [", "]");
$garaza = get_string_between($arduino91, "Garaza: [", "]");
$garazadht = get_string_between($arduino91, "Temperatura v garazi: [", "]");
$garazavl = get_string_between($arduino91, "Vlaga v garazi: [", "]");
$kurnica = get_string_between($arduino91, "Kurnica: [", "]");

echo "Temperatura v kurilnici: $kuriltemp"."<br>";
echo "Pec: $pec1"."<br>";
```

How would I write such code in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all values between `[..]` directly from your `html/text` using regular expressions, i.e. [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Assuming you already fetched that page from your Arduino server, perhaps using the [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) library:

```
import requests
html = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1/").text
# now in html is something like: "<font color=black size=7>...."
```

you can extract those values with:

```
import re
values = re.findall('\[([\d.]+)\]', html)
```

For `html` from your example, `values` variable will contain:

```
['26.00', '33.13', '27.62', '24.00', '17.00', '23.00', '14.00']
```

Now you can say:

```
kurnica = values[0]
garaza = values[2]
...
```

Or if you want to extract all values at once, you can use the destructuring assignment, like this:

```
kurnica, zunaj, garaza, t_garaza, h_garaza, t_kuril, h_kuril = values
```

Comment: @CBox, have you managed to make it work? Is something else unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Now i use this code and work...

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://192.168.5.91")
s = f.read()
f.close()

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

print find_between( s, "Zunaj: [", "]" )
```

Now have problem how declarated find_between to float "test1"

I have to write for each set, this part with def ???

```
    def find_between1( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

print find_between1( s, "Zunaj1: [", "]" )
```

I think like it in my PHP

```
$arduino91 = file_get_contents("http://192.168.5.91/");
$radiator = get_string_between($arduino91, "(povratek): [", "]");
$garaza = get_string_between($arduino91, "Garaza: [", "]");
$garazadht = get_string_between($arduino91, "Temperatura v garazi: [", "]");
$garazavl = get_string_between($arduino91, "Vlaga v garazi: [", "]");
$kurnica = get_string_between($arduino91, "Kurnica: [", "]");
```